# Why I can not use the do{} while(); for control of an operation?

Tags: java, android

Why I can not use the `do{} while();` for control of an operation? For example I want when the `x` variable gets the `5` value, as the result I see the `Finish` message using the `Toast` class. Does this task is not the responsibility of this grammar?

```
do{ 
    //Do some operations
}
while ( there were a condition );
```

So, Why I can not use the `do{} while();` for control of an operation like following code?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    int x;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.re);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.te);
        do {
            relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    x += 1;
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                }
            });

        } while (x == 5);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are adding the click listener while `x == 5` in the loop. This is incorrect. You need to add it once.

You don't need the `do while` construct. Just use `if (x==5) {x+=1;}` inside the listener's `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the functionality you desire, you can write it as:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    int x;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.re);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.te);
        relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                x += 1;
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                if(x == 5) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code:

1. Sets the click listener for the relative layout one time
2. Increments x on each click
3. If clicked 5 times, a toast is shown with the text "Finish"

Other issues with your code:
You seem to use R.id.re when finding both the relative layout and text view, which is incorrect and should cause an exception

Comment: Beat me to it... you should also note that setting a loop to run on the UI thread causes the UI thread to be blocked (effectively removing any user interaction) and rendering the app useless. Run while loops only when necessary, and outside of the UI thread if UI interaction is needed.